# NoSql database for the open source project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nosql

i need to create a website that has a two types of entries. One type is movies with cast, short description, image and a genre (movies can be related and sorted only by genre). And second type of users that creates a movie lists and can sort them by genre and write a little personal comment for movies and lists.
Website will be build in ruby on rails.
Will be expecting all ever created movies to be listed in the database including short movies, and many users that will create lists and notes.
Please tell me what nosql database is most suitable to store this type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good summary of NoSQL databases can be found at http://nosql.findthebest.com/. This provides storage types, license types, and other characteristics of each NoSQL database.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, i have done this type of research. According to my research so far the couchdb is ok for this type of job.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have crazy load assumptions to make and your site is wildly popular you can probably chose any kind of database that you find easiest to use. So whether it is a relational database or a NoSQL Database, pick the one you feel comfortable with. In the end you'll want to use an ORM anyway which will reduce the options. So check out Datamapper, AciveRecord or Mongomapper, Mongoid etc. Those offer Object/Database mappings which is probably the best way to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need NoSQL from the very beginning?

What you describe sounds like a typical use case for a relational database.

Usage of NoSQL comes into play when you need to store non-relational data like files, graphs etc or huge (really huge, like for example Twitter, Facebook, Amazon, …) amounts of data.
As you definitely won't have these amounts of data from the very beginning, just go with the common relational DB approach.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL):

> In short, NoSQL database management systems are useful when working with a huge quantity of data and the data's nature does not require a relational model for the data structure.

Comment: Yes i know that, i work with relation databases each day. My question was about noSql databases because i don’t have experience with them. Thank you anyway.